# How do I change the fontsize of a scalebar in matplotlib?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I know how to set the 'location', 'box_color', 'box_alpha' parameters, etc. in the scalebar argements, using matplotlib_scalebar.scalebar module that I imported. However, when I try to change the fontsize of the scalebar, I don't know how to use the 'font_properties' argument. What should I put in there? Let me know if I didn't ask anything clearly,

Thank you!

[image: 1]

Basically, I want to make this font bigger.

I have tried font_properties = 18, it returns "Unsupported `font_properties`. Pass either a dict or a font config pattern as string."

I've tried font_properties.set_size == 18 and font_properties.set_size = 18, it says "positional argument follows keyword argument", which is not very useful here.

Appreciate your insight!

Answer (score 0):

You must pass `font_properties` as a dictionary. Try `ScaleBar(<other parameters>, font_properties={"size": 18})`